# Capturing GET request params in Node.js

Tags: node.js

I am trying to capture current GET URL and query params in node.js code. I jut realized windows.loication does not work in node.js as it is for client-based execution only. I have tried multiple things but am not able to capture the GET request. Here is what all I have tried.

```
var url = require('url');
var url_parts = url.parse(request.url, true);
var query = url_parts.query;

var request = require('request');
var query = url.parse(request.url,true).query;

getFormattedUrl(req);
function getFormattedUrl(req) {
    console.log("req.url: " + req.url);
    return url.format({
        protocol: req.protocol,
        host: req.get('host')
    });
}
```

All of these fail for me, giving the errors like :

```
2016-12-17T03:32:36.164600+00:00 app[web.1]: ReferenceError: request is not defined

2016-12-17T03:43:46.569603+00:00 app[web.1]: ReferenceError: request is not defined

2016-12-17T03:45:14.509168+00:00 app[web.1]: TypeError: Parameter 'url' must be a string, not undefined
```

Can someone pls suggest how to cpature the GET params in node.js.

Comment: Please be more specific. How do you set your node server? Are you using a generic http server? In that case inside the handler you can access to request.url, but from you question these details are missing

Comment: I am using Heroku to deploy my code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to capture the request that is being made from a NODE JS server to another http/https endpoint for debugging or viewing purposes, this might help

```
var options2 = {
    url: "https://www.google.com",
    port: '443',
    method: 'GET'   
}

request(options2, function(error, response){
    console.log(options2);

    });
```

where options2 is the defined URL the node js server is trying to reach

When you console log options2 (a variable name i've used, you can call it anything), it will give you all the information about the HTTPS/HTTP call the server is making.

Comment: is request a node module i need to add ?

Comment: 2016-12-18T09:56:17.474275+00:00 app[web.1]:

    2016-12-18T09:56:17.626252+00:00 app[web.1]: ReferenceError: request is not defined
    2016-12-18T09:56:17.626253+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/oauth.js:27:1)
    2016-12-18T09:56:17.626251+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
    2016-12-18T09:56:17.626255+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (module.js:356:32)

Comment: ReferenceError: options2 is not defined

Comment: Hi codemonkey, you need to include Options 2 in your code just like i have in the example.

Comment: also yes you need the request module but your sample code above already has it - var request = require('request');

Answer (score 0):

To fix the problem above, just install `request` module from the command line first, before using it:

```
npm install request
```

Interesting things is that to achieve what you need, you do not need to use request module at all. Just use `url` module as you did above, pass request object (not a module, but actual calling request), and format it using [url.format](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#url_url_format_urlobject)

```
const url = require('url')
function getFormattedUrl(req) { return url.format(req.url) }
```

Comment: I thought of the same. But shouldn't Heroku take care of it as well if I deploy it over there ? I am running it on heroku.

Comment: is request module stored in package.json? if not, install it with `npm install request --save`

Comment: updated it, still failing to capture get params. Is it possible for you to share some sample, how to get GET params, alsoI am not sure if I want to use express.js

Comment: updated with working example. you do not need to use express for that.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `express 4.x` then you want [req.query](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.query)

Answer (score 0):

Sample Express JS 4 Code

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Someting')
  console.log(req.query);
})

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!')
})
```

This will launch a localhost server on port 3000

If you do localhost:3000?q=test you will see

```
{q: test}
```

in the console/log.